# Eventos en node js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, jade

Quiero usar una función cuándo se presione un botón.
En el archivo jade ya puse la ruta dónde se encuentra el archivo que tiene la función pero al dar click al botón me dice que el método no está definido.

[image: Este es el código que genera la página web, estoy usando jade]

[image: Actualmente el archivo js que tiene la función está en esta ruta.]

Cuál es la carpeta dónde debo guardar mi archivo js o de que manera se manda a llamar la función?

Comment: Te ayudo mi respuesta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu folder se llama javascripts y el que estas linkeando dice jacascript.

Comment: Sí, ya lo corregí pero aún así no reconoce la función.

Comment: estas trabajando con algún framework de nodejs?

Comment: Usé express-generator para crear el proyecto.

Comment: Acabo de crear un proyecto hacer lo mismo que vos, me funciona el evento, puedes ser mas especifico con el error, te sale algún error en la consola?

Comment: Aca te dejo el proyecto que cree y hice la prueba:
https://github.com/apipemc/example-express-generator

Comment: Sí me sirvió, al parecer el error no era la ruta si no la forma en la que tenía escritos los archivos .jade.
Muchas gracia Andres, ya he corregido mi proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

te falta el .

asi:

```
./jacascript/BuscarEstado.js
```

Comment: @Friky Equis De funciono? si es asi marca como correcto.